# LINQ Extract data from website using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, html-agility-pack, data-extraction

I'm using C# [HTMLAgilityPack](http://%3Chttps://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/%3E) to extract the item name, prices & currency symbol from a chinese website:  https://meadjohnson.world.tmall.com/search.htm?search=y&orderType=defaultSort&s‌​cene=taobao_shop.  Here's a gist of what the html looks like:

```
<div class="SaleItems">
    <dl class="item ">
        <dt class="photo"></dt>
        <dd class="detail">
            <a class="item-name">iPad</a>
            <div class="price-area">
                <span class="symbol">USD</span>
                <span class="price">379</span>
            </div>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="item ">
        <dt class="photo"></dt>
        <dd class="detail">
            <a class="item-name">iPod</a>
            <div class="price-area">
                <span class="symbol">CAD</span>
                <span class="price">139</span>
            </div>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

So far, this is what my program looks like.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
    | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
    | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
    | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

var htmlDocument = htmlWeb.Load(html);
var sItems = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("SaleItems"); 
foreach (var item in sItems)
{
  var data = new {
         Currency  = item["symbol"].InnerText,
         Price = item["price"].InnerText,
         };
}
```

This doesn't work.  How can I fix what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with what you are doing now?

Comment: I get the error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode'"

Answer (score 1):

You can extract your data this way:

```
var input = @"<div class='SaleItems'>
    <dl class='item '>
        <dt class='photo'></dt>
        <dd class='detail'>
            <a class='item-name'>iPad</a>
            <div class='price-area'>
                <span class='symbol'>USD</span>
                <span class='price'>379</span>
            </div>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class='item '>
        <dt class='photo'></dt>
        <dd class='detail'>
            <a class='item-name'>iPod</a>
            <div class='price-area'>
                <span class='symbol'>CAD</span>
                <span class='price'>139</span>
            </div>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>";
var html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(input);
var root = html.DocumentNode;
var list = new List<Data>();
foreach (var node in root.Descendants("dl"))
{
    var currency = node.Descendants()
       .Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("symbol")).FirstOrDefault().InnerText;
    var price = node.Descendants()
       .Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("price")).FirstOrDefault().InnerText;
    list.Add(new Data { Currency = currency, Price = price});
}

public class Data
{
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can use `query expression` instead the `foreach` part:

```
var list = (from node in root.Descendants("dl") 
            let currency = node.Descendants().Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("symbol")).FirstOrDefault().InnerText 
            let price = node.Descendants().Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("price")).FirstOrDefault().InnerText 
            select new Data {Currency = currency, Price = price}).ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  The program doesn't like `root.Descendants("dl")`.

Comment: @inquisitive_one `root` is `doc.DocumentNode.root`

Comment: I changed the `foreach` stmt to `foreach (var node in html.DocumentNode.Descendants("dl")) {`.  It still doesn't work.  Is there something else that I need to change?

Comment: @inquisitive_one What's the error? The code works without any problem on my computer. One more thing `input` contains your HTML as string

Comment: That's the odd part.  I don't get an error.  i'm not getting into the `foreach` loop.  Yes, the `input` i'm using is `https://meadjohnson.world.tmall.com/search.htm?search=y&orderType=defaultSort&scene=taobao_shop`.  I'm not sure why your code doesn't like that site.

Comment: Any ideas on what I should do next?

Answer (score 0):

The exact error is that in the foreach() block "item" is a variable of HtmlNode type but you are trying to "indexing" it. Instead of this you should use

```
item.Descendants("symbol")
```

or

```
item.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='symbol']");
```

Or You can use this code:

```
    var document = new HtmlWeb();
    var root = document.Load(url);
    var data = new List<Item>();
    foreach (var item in root.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//dl"){
        var name = item.SelectSingleNode(".//a[@class='item-name']").InnerText;
        var price = item.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='price']").InnerText;
        var symbol = item.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='symbol']").InnerText;
        data.Add(new Item(){ Name = name, Price = price, Symbol = symbol });
    }
    public class Item{
        public string Name;
        public int Price;
        public string Symbol;
    }
```

Comment: Now, I'm getting "NullReferenceException:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object".  I changed the query to:  `var name = item.SelectSingleNode(".//a[@class='item-name']").InnerText == null ? String.Empty : item.SelectSingleNode(".//a[@class='item-name']").InnerText;`  That didn't work either.  What should I do now?

Comment: Any other ideas that I could use?

Comment: where are you getting exception exactly?

Comment: Note:  the site i'm using is `https://meadjohnson.world.tmall.com/search.htm?search=y&orderType=defaultSort&scene=taobao_shop`.  I'm getting the above mentioned error on `var name = item.SelectSingleNode(".//a[@class='item-name']").InnerText;`.

Comment: see if "item" variable in the foreach block is not null, then clarify if the item with this class name really exists in the page.